# Vertical alignment in a function definion

Tags: vertical-alignment, arrays

I've been trying to figure out how to vertically align the name of the function only with the 2 first line of the definition:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{array}

%___________________________________________________________________

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
%
t_{(u,v)}:
\arraycolsep=1.4pt
%
&\begin{array}{rrl}
    \mathbb{R}^{2}      &\longrightarrow    &\mathbb{R}^{2} \\
    P                   &\longmapsto        &P+(u, v)
\end{array}\\
&\begin{array}{lrl}
    (x, y)                  &\longmapsto &(x, y)+(u, v)     \\
                            &           =&(x+u,\ y+v)
\end{array}
\end{align*}


%___________________________________________________________________

\begin{equation*}
%
t_{(u,v)}:
\arraycolsep=1.4pt
%
\begin{array}{rrl}
    \mathbb{R}^{2}      &\longrightarrow    &\mathbb{R}^{2}     \\
    P                   &\longmapsto        &P+(u, v)           \\
    (x, y)              &\longmapsto        &(x, y)+(u, v)      \\
                        &=                  &(x+u,\ y+v)
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

In the present case, I would have liked $t_{(u,v)}$ to be aligned the way it is in the first example, while keeping the relations aligned like in the second.

Would anyone have an idea?
Thx

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I'm afraid your write-up is a bit confusing. The title says something about aligning a vertical curly brace, but then you say there's no such brace, and the remainder of your write-up doesn't seem to require the presence *or* absence of a vertical curly brace. Please consider clarifying your typesetting objective(s). Thanks.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I was trying to say that I wanted to keep the brace as an option, if desired later on. I have edited this bit out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not at all clear where you want the brace, but I *think* you want something like

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{array}

%___________________________________________________________________

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
%
t_{(u,v)}:
\arraycolsep=1.4pt
%
\biggl\{
\raisebox{.4\baselineskip}{$\begin{array}[t]{rrl}
    \mathbb{R}^{2}      &\longrightarrow    &\mathbb{R}^{2}     \\
    P                   &\longmapsto        &P+(u, v)           \\
    (x, y)              &\longmapsto        &(x, y)+(u, v)      \\
                        &=                  &(x+u,\ y+v)
\end{array}$}
\end{equation*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! I realize my wording was poor, I'll edit it. Thanks!